# RStudio in KDE Neon

Tags: r, rstudio, kde-plasma

How can I install RSudio in KDE Neon I have downloaded rstudio-1.4.1106-amd64.deb and I ran `sudo dpkg -i rstudio-1.4.1106-amd64.deb` in terminal, I got following:

`dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rstudio: rstudio depends on libclang-dev; however: Package libclang-dev is not installed. rstudio depends on libpq5; however: Package libpq5 is not installed.`

`dpkg: error processing package rstudio (--install): dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ... Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ... Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ... Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.15-1) ... Errors were encountered while processing:rstudio`

Answer (score 1):

There are some packages required that are not installed by default. Please try the following, which worked for me on Kubuntu 20.04 recently:

```
URL='https://download1.rstudio.org/desktop/bionic/amd64/rstudio-1.4.1106-amd64.deb'; FILE=`mktemp`; wget "$URL" -qO $FILE && sudo dpkg -i $FILE; rm $FILE
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Answer (score 1):

First I had to find and fix broken packages:

```
apt --fix-broken install
```

Then the package installed correctly for me:

```
sudo dpkg -i rstudio-2022.02.3-492-amd64.deb
```